# Two dimensional induction

Tags: probability-theory, induction

I have the following problem:

I need to prove that given the following integral

$\int_{0}^{1}{c(k,l)x^k(1-x)^l}dx = 1$,

we the constant $c(k,l) = (k+l+1) {{k+l}\choose{k}} = \frac{(k+l+1)!}{k!l!}$,

with the use of two dimensional mathematical induction on $min(k,l)$. 
Here $k$ and $l$ are two nonnegative integers.

(THUS: I need to proof that $c(k,l)$ is equal to $(k+l+1) {{k+l}\choose{k}}$)

For the base step I have proved that $c(k, 0) = c(0, k) = k + 1$ for all $k$.

I am given a hint that for the induction step I could try using integration by parts to show $c(k,l) = \frac{k+1}{l} c(k+1,l−1)$.

By integrating the following by parts I indeed managed to show the latter:

$\int_{0}^{1}{c(k+1,l-1)x^{k+1}(1-x)^{l-1}dx}=1$.

However, I don't really see how this helps me to complete my proof, since I don't really get the idea of two dimensional induction.

Can someone maybe clarify this a bit for me, and help me further with my proof?

Comment: 1) I didn't get what you need to proove. You say that given an integral we can find a constant. Of course, we can, we don't even need that integral to calculate the constant. 2) In the hint, there are two Unicode symbols those don't display correctly for me. Can you please tell me what symbols are near the $k+1$ at the beginning? Please, parse special symbols using MathJax.

Comment: Yeah sorry, that wasn't very clear indeed. I changed it, is it clear now?

Comment: Is the integral supposed to be equal to something?  You don't really have a "given".

Comment: Yeah sorry, also changed that, sorry for all the inconveniences!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In some sense, I think we don't need two-dimensional induction here. Assume that you showed the recurrence relation
$$
c(k, l) = \frac{k+1}{l}c(k+1, l-1)
$$
by using the integration by parts. Also, we know base case: $c(k, 0) = c(0, k) = k+1$. Then 
$$
c(k, l) = \frac{k+1}{l} c(k+1, l-1) = \frac{k+1}{l} \frac{k+2}{l-1} c(k+2, l-2) \\= \cdots = \frac{(k+1)(k+2)\cdots(k+l)}{l(l-1)\cdots1}c(k+l, 0)= \frac{(k+1)(k+2)\cdots (k+l+1)}{l(l-1)\cdots 2\cdot 1} = \frac{(k+l+1)!}{k!l!}
$$

---

If you want to use induction, you can write in this way: First, we know $c(k, 0) = k+1$ for all $k$. (This is a base step) 
Assume that $c(k, l) =\frac{(k+l+1)!}{k!l!}$ is true for all $k$ and $l \leq L$. For $l = L+1$, we have
$$
c(k, L+1) = \frac{k+1}{L+1} c(k+1, L) = \frac{k+1}{L+1} \frac{(k+L+2)!}{(k+1)!L!} = \frac{(k+L+2)!}{k!(L+1)!}
$$
so it is also true for $l = L+1$.

Answer (score 2):

Let me give you an intuitive hint on how to deal with 2D induction

[image: 2D_Induction_1]

You have demonstrated that the hypothesis is true on the axis $k=0$, for whichever $l$ in the domain of interest ($[0,\infty )$ in this case).

You have demonstrated that if the hypothesis is true for $(l,k)$ then it is true for $(l-1,k+1)$.
Therefore it is true for the whole diagonal line shown in the sketch, going from $(l,0)$ to $(0,l)$.

Thus, it is true for any  such diagonal line, starting from whichever point $(l,0)$.

These lines cover all the points in $[0, \infty)^2$ and thus the hypothesis is true  over all such a domain.

If the recursion had been $(l,k)\, \to \, (l+1,k+1)$ then it is clear that you should have started from demonstrating that the hypothesis is true on $(l,0)$ and $(0,k)$
to be able to cover all the quadrant.

Answer (score 1):

Integration by parts relates $I_{k,l}$ to $I_{k+1,l-1}$. So by setting $l=n-k$, you relate $I_{k,n-k}$ to $I_{k+1,n-(k+1)}$, which forms an ordinary induction on $k$. The $I_{0,n}$ are elementary.